# How do i move my .PlayOnLinux

Tags: 16.04, wine, playonlinux, winetricks

I want to move the .PlayOnLinux directory so that I dont have to install games on to my ssd, because the space on it is very limited.

Can i just move the folder to my hard drive or will that mess everything up? How should I go about doing it?

Comment: You want to move it and then continue using PlayOnLinux?  Or you just want to temporarily move it?

Comment: move it and use it. I want to move it so that i can play and install games to my hard drive instead of my ssd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `.PlayOnLinux` folder to it's new location on your other hard drive.

Let's say you've mounted this at `/media/user/exthd`

So move your folder, using either a GUI file manager, or a terminal command like so:

`mv ~/.PlayOnLinux /media/user/exthd`

Now create a symlink back to where it was

`ln -s /media/user/exthd/.PlayOnLinux ~/.PlayOnLinux`

The symlink is like a shortcut to where you moved it.  As far as the system is concerned, it's still in the same location.